# detect packet fragmentation in kernel module netfilter hooking

Tags: c, network-programming, linux-kernel

I am not able to detect if packet fragmented or not and packet offset.

I dump header data

```
 printk("frt_offset=%d ", ((ip_header->frag_off)));//print all, not 13 bytes of it
 printk("fr_cf=%d ", (ntohs(ip_header->frag_off) & IP_CE) > 0);
 printk("frt_df=%d ", (ntohs(ip_header->frag_off) & IP_DF) > 0);
 printk("fr_mf=%d ", (ntohs(ip_header->frag_off) & IP_MF) > 0);
```

but when I downloaded file with module enabled I got this output:

```
[40432.831134] packet size=1514 timestamp=-790555865  frt_id=60370 frt_offset=64 fr_xf=0    frt_df=1 fr_mf=0
[40432.831318] packet size=1514 timestamp=-790371858  frt_id=60626 frt_offset=64 fr_xf=0 frt_df=1 fr_mf=0 
[40432.831496] packet size=1514 timestamp=-790193971 frt_id=60882 frt_offset=64 fr_xf=0   frt_df=1 fr_mf=0 
[40432.831905] packet size=1514 timestamp=-789785167 frt_id=61138 frt_offset=64 fr_xf=0 frt_df=1 fr_mf=0 
[40432.832098] packet size=1514 timestamp=-789592131 frt_id=61394 frt_offset=64 fr_xf=0 frt_df=1 fr_mf=0 
[40432.832504] packet size=1514 timestamp=-789186978 frt_id=61650 frt_offset=64 fr_xf=0 frt_df=1 fr_mf=0 
[40436.131049] packet size=45 timestamp=-1785619342 frt_id=4464 frt_offset=0 fr_xf=0 frt_df=0 fr_mf=0
```

But as I understood, for fragmented packets I must got the same id, various offset, flag mf=1. We have something another here. Last packet here may be packet from another session.

I lost my way...

Comment: Are you sure the packets really were fragmented ?

Comment: oh, now I am really not sure about this. thank you

Comment: In which hook points are you checking for fragments (Local in, post routing, etc..)?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know when using netfilter hooks the `ip_local_deliver` function in the kernel will defragment ip packets before calling hooks registered for `LOCAL_IN`. Locally generated packets are fragmented in the `ip_finished_output` function called after hooks for `POST_ROUTING` are run.

In sum, looking at the kernel code tells me that you can only grab fragments in `PRE_ROUTING`, `FORWARD` (If not local generated) and `POST_ROUTING` (If not local generated) hooks.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

This is a good one like a puzzle..you just give in a random output of a bunch of packets.Well "we" can only guess unless you throw in more info or a PCAP.There be be many scenarios, 
You need to check for the following

1.If offset 0

> this may me fragmented and is the first packet if MF=1 
>   or
>   may not be fragmented easily MF=0

2.If offset is something else then you can be definitive bout fragmentation

According to the output which you have put up (are the last packets of some fragmented packets Multiply the offset by 8 )
First with your output
ok before that
1. Are you trying to apply the hook on LOCAL_IN or LOCAL_OUT or PRE_ROUTING
2.Whats the MTU set i assume 1500
well anyway the Packet Size in your output shown is 1514(and i suppose tats the size of the packet on wire)

AND

As you can see the DF (Do not fragment bit) is set and MF(More fragment) is Zero(may be the LAST packet )
Try doing this

ping -s 2000 www.google.com and check the output  close off all other open connections(browers downloads etc)

WELL CONCLUSION THOSE ARE FRAGMENTED PACKETS except the last one i suppose :D :D cheers